# cascade Printing in python

Tags: python, string, printing, cascade

I want to write a program that shows the text in a cascading way Like This:

```
......
      ......
            ......
```

and my main problem is displaying the data.
I searched this site, and these are the pieces of code I wrote the program based on.

[Print user input in “cascade” of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120698/print-user-input-in-cascade-of-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the correct answer:

```
    a="******"
    for i in range(0,3):
  
    print("\t"*(i+1),a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code in `cascade_name` in `Python 3` it won't work. Enclose print statement in brackets.

```
for index, value in enumerate("name"):
    print(" "*index,value)
```

Why code like this wouldn't work?

replace `"name"` with input and you are good to go.
Instead of `" "` you can input as many spaces in cascading as you want.